# data encoding for JSON.parse( ) unexpected token

Tags: javascript, json, character-encoding

I am pulling down some data from my server and manipulating it and then trying to load the string into an object using `JSON.parse()`. However whenever I try to do it I get an `Unexpected Token`  error. The weird thing is that usually chrome tells me what the unexpected token is (usually 'o' or something). This time it is just a space. Which makes me think that there is some type of ascii encoding error or something going on. If I print the json string to the console doing `console.log()` and then paste it directly into the code then it has no problem parsing the string.

```
 var testString = '[ { "pk": 1663, "state": "IO", "group": "ALO", "species": "", "application_link": "" } ]';
var testObject = JSON.parse(testString);
alert(testObject);
```

Works exactly how I expect it to. But this doesn't:

```
function hex2ascii(hexx) { //stolen off stackoverflow
    var hex = hexx.toString();//force conversion
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2)
        str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
    return str;
}

function decodeData(encoded){
    var original_string = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < encoded.length; i+=2) {
        var index = i/2;
        var hex_value = encoded[i]+encoded[i+1];
        var ochar = hex2ascii(hex_value);
        original_string += ochar;
    }
    return original_string;
}
$.get(url, function(data) {
     var testString = decodeData(data); //decodeData grabs a hex string and then decodes it into a json formatted string
    var testObject = JSON.parse(testString); //Unexpected Token
    alert(testObject);
});
```

Anybody have any ideas on how to go about troubleshooting this?

Edit:
I don't know why but I have a bunch of null's in my string. When I iterate through the json string and convert it back to hex I get:

```
hex_string = ''
for(var i = 0; i < decoded_data.length; i++){
    if (i < 10){ 
        alert(decoded_data[i]);
    }
    hex_string += ascii2hex(decoded_data[i])+' ';
}
console.log(hex_string);

>>>0 0 5b 0 0 7b 0 0 22 0 0 70 0 0 6b 0 0 22 0 0 3a 0 0 20 0 0 31 0 0 36 0 0 36 0 0
```

Edit again:

Ok so I have pinned it down to my concatenation method. For some reason in the decodeData function when I concatenate it together doing

```
original_string += ochar;
```

It's throwing in a bunch of null characters. Is there another way to concatenate the string together?

**Edit answer:**

Ok, so the problem lied within the hex2ascii function. It was adding in a bunch of null characters. It was code I stole off of stack overflow and wasn't what I expected. I ended up changing it to this and now it's golden.

```
function hex2ascii(hexx) {
   var hex = hexx.toString();//force conversion
   return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex, 16));
}
```

Comment: what does `decodeData` do?

Comment: please, show the contents of testString

Comment: the testString is really really long. I am going to try to shorten it and see if it still breaks.

Comment: Did you try use some json validator to validate value from testString? I use this [http://jsonlint.com/](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: When I pull the data from the server and then copy and paste it into the validator it works.

Comment: How come `decodeData` has two parameters `key` and `encoded` and when you call `decodeData` you only pass one argument? I don't understand how you get output.

Comment: sorry, that was a stack overflow copy paste error.

Answer (score 1):

you could not juz input break line in javascript string, it will make it invalid.

**Invalid**

```
var testString = '[ {
        "pk": 1663,
        "state": "IO",
        "group": "ALO",
        "species": ""
]}';
```

**Valid**

```
var testString = '[ {"pk": 1663,"state": "IO","group": "ALO","species": ""]}';
```

Comment: Yeah, that was a copy and paste error. It was all on one line when I ran it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the reason you are getting an Unexpected Token error is because you have that extra close parenthesis on the line that says

```
$.get(url, function(data)) {
```

and you are missing a parenthesis at the end.

Comment: Good catch. That was a copy/paste error to stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem lied within the hex2ascii function. It was adding in a bunch of null characters. It was code I stole off of stack overflow and wasn't what I expected. I ended up changing it to this and now it's golden.

```
function hex2ascii(hexx) {
   var hex = hexx.toString();//force conversion
   return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex, 16));
}
```